# iOS Inapp purchase after subscription upcell cancellation_date_ms value is still empty

Tags: ios, subscription

We are implementing an auto-renewable subscription in our app.

Currently, we have checked cancellation_date_ms has a date value inside of receipts when upgrade subscription in same subscription group. And also received Server to Server Notifications 'Cancel' notification.

But sometimes when we doing upgrade the subscription, cancellation_date_ms does not have values and not receiving Server Notifications.

In our app, it's vital to stop service when users upgrade the subscription.
We want to know all cases cancelling user's subscription when they have upgrade their auto-renewable subscription.

Please share if you know something.

Comment: I would suggest a different approach; check the receipt's active subscriptions and activate the "highest" IAP that is currently active.  If the user "upgrade so within a group the upgrade takes effect immediately. If they downgrade it takes effect at the next renewal date.

Comment: That's good tips. Thanks !